# ngrx store does not update subscription when object is updated

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

Now I understand there are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098421/ngrx-store-subscription-not-called-when-state-changes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859058/ngrx-subscribed-store-does-not-update-on-state-change-angular5) but they've only given me half the answer,

Basically what is happening is in my reducer file I have an update method like so

```
import * as UserActions from '../actions/user.actions';
import { UserDto } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';

export function userReducer(state: UserDto[] = null, action: 
UserActions.Actions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActions.SET_USERS:
        return action.payload;
    case UserActions.UPDATE_USER:
        if (state === null) { state = []; }
        let index = state.findIndex(x => x.id === action.payload.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
            state[index] = action.payload;
        } else {
            state.push(action.payload);
        }
        return state;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

now whats happening is update is being called, altering the state and returning the new state, but its not triggering my state subscription, now from the other questions I can gather this is because 'technically' its the same state object, just with certain objects changed, how In this circumstance can I trigger my subscription??

I tried to create a new variable like so and then return that but it still thinks its the same object

```
let newState = state;
return state
```

what would be the best solution here??

Comment: Maybe with `return state ? [...state] : state;` or `return state ? state.slice(0) : state;`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as you say, you're mutating the existing state and not creating new. You should be using the spread operator to return new objects in most cases.

```
return { ...state, action.payload };
```